# Logstash is not pushing json format files

Tags: json, logstash

I am new in Elasticsearch,Kibana et Logstash. I am trying to load a json file like this one:

```
{"timestamp":"2014-05-19T00:00:00.430Z","memoryUsage":42.0,"totalMemory":85.74,"usedMemory":78.77,"cpuUsage":26.99,"monitoringType":"jvmHealth"}
{"timestamp":"2014-05-19T00:09:10.431Z","memoryUsage":43.0,"totalMemory":85.74,"usedMemory":78.77,"cpuUsage":26.99,"monitoringType":"jvmHealth"}
{"timestamp":"2014-05-19T00:09:10.441Z","transactionTime":1,"nbAddedObjects":0,"nbRemovedObjects":0,"monitoringType":"transactions"}
{"timestamp":"2014-05-19T00:09:10.513Z","transactionTime":6,"nbAddedObjects":4,"nbRemovedObjects":0,"monitoringType":"transactions"}
```

No index is created and I just get this message :

> Using milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable,
>   but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more
>   information on plugin milestones, see
>   http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}

What can be the problem? I can use directly bulk but I must go with logstash.
Do you have any suggested code that can help?

EDIT (to move the config from a comment into the question):

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/ndoye/Elasticsearch/great_log.json"
        type => json
        codec => json
    }
}

filter {
    date {
        match => ["timestamp","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    }
}

output {
    stdout{
        #codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        embedded => true
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to do exactly what the message suggests.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but what need to be done is not explicitly explained.

Comment: "If you see strange behavior, let us know."

Comment: Let us know how you try to load your json file. Have you auto creation of index enabled in elasticsearch? Is you logstash configured? Please provide more information.

Comment: Thanks Robert and Deagh. Here we go with the code that I used. input{
  file{
     path => "/home/ndoye/Elasticsearch/great_log.json"
     type  => json
     codec => json
  }
}

filter{
  
  date{
     match =>["timestamp","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
 }
}

output {
  stdout{
    #codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}

Comment: you should edit your question to put the config in the queuestion (so it can be formatted correctly)